# EF6 - selection does not match with child table data

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Here is my classes:

1

```
public partial class SmsScheduleType
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

2

```
public partial class SmsSchedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SiteId")]
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }

    public int ScheduleTypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual SmsScheduleType SmsScheduleType { get; set; }

    public int DateToSend { get; set; }
    public int DayOfWeekToSend { get; set; }
    public string TimeToSend { get; set; }
    public string TextToSend { get; set; }
    public int Interval { get; set; }
}
```

Here is a SmsScheduleType data

```
**Id  Name**
1; "Running"
3; "Weekly"
4; "Monthly"
5; "Daily"
2; "Idle"
```

And this is

```
**Id SiteId DayOfWeekToSend TextToSend ScheduleTypeId DateToSend TimeToSend Interval Active**
2;     1;              0;  "Daily test";         5;          0;    "1500";    0;     t
4;     3;              0;  "Daily test";         1;          0;        "";   60;     f
5;     4;              0;     "Monthly";         4;          8;   "11:00";    0;     t
```

Query

```
var ready2send = context.SmsSchedules.ToList();
    foreach (var sch in ready2send)
    {                        
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is scheduled as {1}-{2}, {3}.", sch.Site.SiteID, sch.ScheduleTypeId ,sch.SmsScheduleType.Name, sch.SmsScheduleType.Id);
    }
```

Query result

```
BHE152 is scheduled as 5-Idle, 2.
BHE155 is scheduled as 1-Monthly, 4.
BHE156 is scheduled as 4-Daily, 5.
```

I cannot understand what is wrong. Why Ids are not matching?
please help
DB is postgres if it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
public partial class SmsSchedule
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int SiteId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("SiteId")]
    public virtual Site Site { get; set; }

    public int ScheduleTypeId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ScheduleTypeId ")]
    public virtual SmsScheduleType SmsScheduleType { get; set; }

    public int DateToSend { get; set; }
    public int DayOfWeekToSend { get; set; }
    public string TimeToSend { get; set; }
    public string TextToSend { get; set; }
    public int Interval { get; set; }
}
```

Note that I changed

```
[ForeignKey("Id")]
```

to

```
[ForeignKey("ScheduleTypeId ")]
```

When you use `[ForeignKey("Id")]` you tell EF that you store foreign key of `SmsScheduleType` table in `Id` filed of *SmsSchedule* table